# Move factory method from AppModule to AppComponent in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-module

I use [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader](https://github.com/denniske/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader) loader to create specific translations. The documentation requires that this factory has to be created within the app.module.ts:

```
export function multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/default/', suffix: '.json'},
    {prefix: './assets/i18n/bc/', suffix: '.json'}
  ]);
}
```

This factory is configured inside the import arrays in this way:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}),
```

I need a way to put the factory into my app.component.ts, because I still have to program some logic and do not want to do that within my app.module.ts.

But if I move the method into my app.component.ts and make all the necessary import statements on top of the file, angular doesn't compile and returns this error message:

> ERROR in src / app / app.module.ts (55,21): error TS2304: Can not find
>   name 'multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory'.

Is there a possibility or do I really have to define the factory within app.module.ts ???

Comment: will your factory method in the file `app.component.ts` or even in the component?

Comment: Hmm, I just do not know you mean. I want to move the factory to app.component.ts, so my AppModule is empty.

Comment: could you update the question with the code you currently use? (with the factory in `app.component.ts` and how you use it in your module)

Answer (score 0):

It really should not matter where you define your factory, or any other function for that matter. Just be sure to import it correctly, somewhere in the top of `app.module.ts`

```
import {multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory} from 'path/to/your/component'
```

Comment: True, I did not think about the import. It just wondered me that it was placed in the AppModule as an exported function. I‘ll try it tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I have just noticed that I can not use the function as an exported function, but must call within my AppComponent class, so I have access to my services. Is there a possibility for that?

Comment: you can inject services in a factory function. there is no need to instanciate a whole component.
which will lead to problems anyway, because components are not meant to be used like that.
If you show us your code including all the services you need, we can better help you :)